# MySQL/JPA : How create a correclty relation and cascade?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, jpa, jpa-2.0

I was very impress with my project, but suddenly I notice that I am doing something very wrong, 'cause, every create, merge, delete I was doing manually, but I should let the JPA take care of that for me right ?

What I do, is create the database then create the entities from it. So [here is my database](http://pastebin.com/6dAfmryt) so you guys can understand my concept issue.

In a simple way:
An `user` has an `address`, only one address. This `address` is composed by `city`, `state` and `country`. I want to be able to create, update the `user address` by cascade.

I think my mapping, generated by JPA is wrong (or my understaing is wrong), let me show it:

```
public class User {
  ..
  //bi-directional many-to-one association to UserAddress
  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) // should be one to one ?
  @JoinColumn(name="id_user_address")
  private UserAddress userAddress;
  ..
}

public class UserAddress {
  ..

  //bi-directional many-to-one association to User
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="userAddress", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
  private List<User> users;

  //bi-directional many-to-one association to AddressCity
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="id_city")
  private AddressCity addressCity;

  //bi-directional many-to-one association to AddressState
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="id_state")
  private AddressState addressState;

  //bi-directional many-to-one association to AddressCountry
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="id_country")
  private AddressCountry addressCountry;
  ..
}
```

What I think is that the `user` has `one adress only`, so it should be `OneToOne` mapping ?
And the same goes for `UserAdress` about `country`, `state` and `city`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to allow multiple users on the same address @ManyToOne is what you want. If you use @OneToOne you can have only one user per address.

Comment: @Elke, this is what I want, one user has one address only, but I don't know how to do it..

Comment: What you have is correct and does what you want. ManyToOne and OneToOne both give you a single address per user. The difference is in the number of users per address. Going by the fact that you have a list of users in your UserAddress entity you want a ManyToOne mapping in your User entity.

Comment: Now I got it.
Thanks dude!